Not able to print variable values from one step to different step in github workflow
As set:output is deprecated, the new method is GITHUB_ENV
- name: Set variables based on condition
        id: set-variables
        run: |
          $context = '${{ toJson(github) }}'
          $contextObject = $context | ConvertFrom-Json
          $REPO_NAME = $contextObject.event.client_payload.REPO_NAME
          echo $REPO_NAME
          $componentName = $REPO_NAME -split '/' | Select-Object -Last 1
          echo $componentName
          echo "COMPONENT_NAME=$componentName" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: Use Component Name
        run: |
          echo "The component name is: $COMPONENT_NAME"

the component name is not printing and giving a empty value, expecting to get the value in the next stage

Please edit and use above and under the code block so its readable. You can also in the top one useyaml to give a hint to the editor how to interpret your code.

Setting an output was replaced by writing to $GITHUB_OUTPUT; $GITHUB_ENV is to set environment variables. Also, check the docs and look at the correct syntax for PowerShell.

@BenjaminW. Thanks this worked
